# Передать в Javascript переменную из массива JSON файла Сookie

Tags: javascript, массивы, json

Подскажите, как передать одну переменную в Javascript, сохраненную в JSON массиве значения файла Сookie?

Сookie записывается таким образом:

```
$cookie_key = 'count';
CookieManager::store($cookie_key, json_encode(array(
    'SameSite' => 'None',
         ...
    'lastvisit' => $time,
    'token' => $counts->token)));
```

Отсюда нужно переменную 'token' передать в JS, на той же странице, избегая при этом вставки php-кода `<?php $token; ?>`

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie